# Depency on SBCL installing ROS from source (ARM Hardware)

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, pandaboard, odroid, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people,

i tried to install the new ROS Indigo Beta from source on my ARM Hardware (just the Bare-Bones). Everything runs fine until installing the depencies through "rosdep install". There is one package "SBCL" where no binary is found for the ARM Hardware. I already know this issue from Hydro (and I think even in Groovy). I can remove the packages which depend on SBCL manually, but I think it would be better to find a solution for solving this depency for Indigo Igloo as LTS version. This would be a big step for supporting ARM Hardware. I think even the Desktop Install could work then from Source.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172498/depency-on-sbcl-installing-ros-from-source-(arm-hardware)/) by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2014-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**UPDATE**

I now have experimental debs available for Indigo on Trusty armhf, including builds of sbcl: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The trouble here is that there are no builds of SBCL for the Ubuntu arm variants, and it at the time when I did builds of ROS Hydro for ARM, it looked like it would be difficult to port SBCL to arm and build the required binary packages.

The [SBCL news page](http://www.sbcl.org/news.html) indicates that SBCL has recently been ported to ARM Linux, so it may be possible to build debs for armhf now.

If you have time to build debs of SBCL for Ubuntu ARM, I'd be more than happy to include them in my ROS ARM repository and build debs against them.

**EDIT**

I have deb builds of SBCL that will be part of the upcoming Indigo for ARM release: http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros_support/pool/main/s/sbcl/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just dealt with all of this yesterday on a SolidRun CuBox-i Pro. My solution was:

1. Install the SBCL armhf binaries for SBCL 1.2.1:
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/sbcl/files/sbcl/1.2.1/sbcl-1.2.1-armhf-linux-binary.tar.bz2/download?use_mirror=superb-dca2
2. Use that install to bootstrap 1.2.2 from source and install it (this step is probably optional)
3. Used equivs to create and install a fake (and empty) sbcl package so that Ubuntu would see the dependency as satisfied: http://eric.lubow.org/2010/system-administration/creating-dummy-packages-on-debian/

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2